# Fixing the WP Post Object for Custom Route

Tags: posts, plugin-development, permalinks, url-rewriting

I'm currently in the process of building a custom plugin for a client that involves displaying front end user profiles for any "subscribers". These profiles will be populated with various user meta as well as forms for updating this usermeta. It's a basic networking / social profile site for a specific niche industry.

I've had to do this for various projects in the past as well, and I've always tackled the problem by creating custom routes off of the `template_include` hook. Essentially, I hook in to WP to see if the URL matches a specified regex, and if so, I deliver a custom page template to the user. Essentially, this bypasses WordPress' built in page system and delivers a template that can be used for displaying user info.

For example, imagine this URL:

`examplesite.com/user/joe-smith/`

My plugin is set up to manually redirect this to a template that I've included in my plugin core. This template then looks up the user based on the URL entered, and displays certain meta fields using the included template.

This all works great, however when I try to load the `global $post` object and utilize it anywhere on the page, it returns the values of the "Hello World" blog post. Also, the `<body>` tag on the page automatically gets assigned `class="blog"`, which causes it to inherit blog specific styling.

My question is, how can I "reset" the WP Post object to contain useful info? Would it be considered bad practice to manually populate the WP Post object before I load my template? Am I going about this all wrong? I would appreciate any insight that anyone can provide me.

EDIT:

Below is my sample code from the site in question:

```
/**
 * class CM_Permalink_Registration
 * 
 * This class is responsible for creating any custom permalinks meant to be used by the site 
 * These are hard coded routes that will return different templates included with our plugin
 **/

class CM_Permalink_Registration {

    /**
     * A reference to an instance of this class.
     */
    private static $instance;

    public $dependencies = null;

    private $permalinks_to_register = array();

    public $plugin_template_path = null;
    public $theme_template_path = null;


    private function __construct($dependencies){

        $this->dependencies = $dependencies;

        $this->plugin_template_path = $dependencies['cm_manager']->plugin_path.'core/page-templates/hard-coded/';
        $this->theme_template_path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/cm-plugin-templates/';
        $this->theme_path = get_stylesheet_directory().'/';



        $this->permalinks_to_register = array(
            array(
                'template_filename' => 'city-directory-page.php',
                'route' => '^financial-advisor-(.+)/?$',
                'rewrite' => 'index.php?location=$matches[1]',
                'rewrite_tags' => array(
                    array(
                        'tag' => '%location%',
                        'regex' => '([^&]+)'
                    )
                ),
                'conditional' => 'return isset($wp->query_vars["location"]) && $this->dependencies["states_cities"]->is_valid_location_url($wp->query_vars["location"]);'
            ),
            array(
                'template_filename' => 'advisor-profile.php',
                'route' => '^(.+)-cfp/?$',
                'rewrite' => 'index.php?advisor=$matches[1]',
                'rewrite_tags' => array(
                    array(
                        'tag' => '%advisor%',
                        'regex' => '([^&]+)'
                    )
                ),
                'conditional' => 'return isset($wp->query_vars["advisor"]) && $this->dependencies["advisor"]->is_valid_advisor_url($wp->query_vars["advisor"]);'
            ),
            array(
                'template_filename' => 'advisor-profile-editor.php',
                'route' => '^edit-profile/(.+)/?$',
                'rewrite' => 'index.php?edit=true&edit-advisor=$matches[1]',
                'rewrite_tags' => array(
                    array(
                        'tag' => '%edit-advisor%',
                        'regex' => '([^&]+)'
                    )
                ),
                'conditional' => 'return isset($wp->query_vars["edit-advisor"]) && $this->dependencies["advisor"]->is_valid_advisor_url($wp->query_vars["edit-advisor"]);'
            )
        );


        $this->register_init_hook();
        $this->register_template_redirect_hook();
    }


    /**
     * Returns an instance of this class. 
     */
    public static function get_instance($dependencies){
        if( null == self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new CM_Permalink_Registration($dependencies);
        } 
        return self::$instance;
    }


    /**
     * public function register_custom_permalinks()
     * 
     * This function registers our new routes with wordpress by adding rewrite rules
    **/

    public function register_custom_permalinks(){
        foreach($this->permalinks_to_register as $permalink){
            add_rewrite_rule($permalink['route'], $permalink['rewrite'], 'bottom');
            foreach($permalink['rewrite_tags'] as $tag){
                add_rewrite_tag($tag['tag'], $tag['regex']);
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * public function deliver_custom_templates()
     * 
     * This function hooks into the template redirect hook and checks to see if the entered URL meets the specified conditions to display a custom template
    **/

    public function deliver_custom_templates($return_template){
        global $wp;

        $found_valid_page = false;

        foreach($this->permalinks_to_register as $permalink){
            if(eval($permalink['conditional'])){
                if (file_exists($this->theme_template_path . $permalink['template_filename'])) {
                    $return_template = $this->theme_template_path . $permalink['template_filename'];
                } 
                else{
                    $return_template = $this->plugin_template_path . $permalink['template_filename'];
                }
                $found_valid_page = true;
            }
        }
        if($found_valid_page){
            include($return_template);
            die();
        }
        else{
            global $post, $wp_query;
            foreach($this->permalinks_to_register as $permalink){
                if (preg_match('&'.$permalink['route'].'&', ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')) !== 0 && !eval($permalink['conditional'])){
                    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found - Archive Empty");
                    require $this->theme_path.'404.php';
                    exit;
                    $wp_query->is_404 = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return_template;
    }


    /**
     * private function register_template_redirect_hook()
     * 
     * This function is responsible for hooking in our register_custom_permalinks() method to the template_redirect hook
    **/

    private function register_template_redirect_hook(){
        add_action("template_include", array(&$this, 'deliver_custom_templates'));
    }

    private function register_init_hook(){
        add_action('init', array(&$this, 'register_custom_permalinks'));
    }

}
```

Specifically, you can see the rewrite rule / rewrite tag registration setup here:

```
foreach($this->permalinks_to_register as $permalink){
    add_rewrite_rule($permalink['route'], $permalink['rewrite'], 'bottom');
    foreach($permalink['rewrite_tags'] as $tag){
        add_rewrite_tag($tag['tag'], $tag['regex']);
    }
}
```

For query vars, I'm using add_rewrite_tag to register a new query var for each endpoint. For example, the rewrite rule for one of my pages looks like this:

`'rewrite' => 'index.php?advisor=$matches[1]'`

The only query var I explicitly set is a new custom "advisor" variable. Should I be setting something else to make this work correctly?

Comment: Can we see the rewrite rule and the query vars being used? Those query vars are used in the main loop query ( they're passed into a WP_Query )

Comment: I've updated the initial post to contain some more info. Thank you :)

Comment: I would just use a page as the base for your rules, you won't need to "fix" anything, the main query will always contain that page's data and templates will work as expected. If you need to modify any template tag output (the_content, body_class, etc.,), there are filters for that.

Comment: I suppose I could add an init hook to the plugin to create the new required page if it doesn't already exist. This seems to be how plugins like WooCommerce operate. Would there be any drawbacks to going this route or would this be a better path to go in general?

Comment: I don't see any drawbacks. It fits your requirements, and gives users some control if they want to change the slug or name. You could also do away with custom templates and do everything in a content filter, if you want to make it totally theme-independent. You might want to also look at the [`admin_post` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_post_(action)), if you want to set up a post/redirect/get pattern and do all your form handling within `admin_post` hooks.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info. If you want to place this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it. I ended up going with  `register_activation_hook()` to create the necessary pages on plugin activation, and I use the same rewrite rules but also added in a "pagename" parameter to load the custom page I created. I also have page templates for each page automatically registered by the plugin, and they can be over-ridden by the theme. Very WooCommerce-esque. Thanks for your insight.